# Install Facebook Pixel Purchase event to a Button manually?

Tags: javascript, shopify, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

Here is my Facebook Ad account Pixel code:

```
<script>
   !(function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
      if (f.fbq) return;
      n = f.fbq = function () {
         n.callMethod ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments);
      };
      if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
      n.push = n;
      n.loaded = !0;
      n.version = "2.0";
      n.queue = [];
      t = b.createElement(e);
      t.async = !0;
      t.src = v;
      s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
   })(window, document, "script", "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");
   fbq("init", "XXXX");
   fbq("track", "PageView");
</script>
<noscript
   ><img
      height="1"
      width="1"
      style="display: none;"
      src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

And here is the Buy It Now button code:

```
<button
   class="button_get order_button btn btn-pink js_submit button__text orderButton"
   id="send"
   type="submit"
   onClick="fbq('track', 'Purchase');"
>
   Buy It Now
</button>
```

And here is the JavaScript onClick button Pixel Tracking Code:

```
function onClick() { fbq('track',
'Purchase', { value: {{line_item.original_line_price | money}}, currency: {{currency.name}}, }); };
```

Screenshot of the error message that I get when check using Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension:
[image: fb pixel helper]

Comment: Any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: I still need your help guys!

Answer (score -1):

try this :
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 0.00,currency: 'USD'});

Comment: Can you provide some context to explain your code and why your answer works?